# Group by Row Categories

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script that will collect each group category from the rows. 
Each category could have different amount of items.
I'd love to be able to identify the last row from each category so I can create a script to add a new row for a specific category.

I don't want to rely on the categories by the number of row. But rather by the background color of each title.

Here's the document: https://docs.google.com/a/helloinnovation.com/spreadsheets/d/1MWLb_si29kkqBdFAuXUee6ZmZTU0D1j2PxLWa8PUrQs/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The end of one category is the Title of the next category.  You can add a note to a cell, and you can use the `getNote()` method to get the note.

[Google Documentation - getNote()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNote())

So, you can find the end of the previous section by putting a note into the heading of the next section, then use code to check the note in the cell.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A4");
var data = range.getValues(),
    thisCell;

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i+=1) {
  thisCell = sheet.getRange(i+2, 1);
  Logger.log(thisCell.getNote());

  if (thisCell.getNote() === 'end') {
    sheet.insertRowBefore(i+1);
  };
}
```